# How to define a variable that can be undefined in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, typesafe-actions

I am using [typesafe-actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions) and I have the following declaration:

```
function getAction<Payload>():PayloadAC<string, Payload>  {
    const p = createStandardAction('FETCH')<Payload>();
    return p; // <------- Here is get typescript error
}
```

(This method is only an example that clarify my question, it is not a real function in my code)
This code produce typescript error:

```
Type '[Payload] extends [undefined] ? unknown extends Payload ? PayloadAC<"FETCH", Payload> : EmptyAC<"FETCH"> : PayloadAC<"FETCH", Payload>' is not assignable to type 'PayloadAC<string, Payload>'.
  Type '(unknown extends Payload ? PayloadAC<"FETCH", Payload> : EmptyAC<"FETCH">) | PayloadAC<"FETCH", Payload>' is not assignable to type 'PayloadAC<string, Payload>'.
    Type 'unknown extends Payload ? PayloadAC<"FETCH", Payload> : EmptyAC<"FETCH">' is not assignable to type 'PayloadAC<string, Payload>'.
      Type 'PayloadAC<"FETCH", Payload> | EmptyAC<"FETCH">' is not assignable to type 'PayloadAC<string, Payload>'.
        Type 'EmptyAC<"FETCH">' is not assignable to type 'PayloadAC<string, Payload>'.
          Property 'payload' is missing in type 'EmptyAction<"FETCH">' but required in type 'PayloadAction<string, Payload>'.ts(2322)
type-helpers.d.ts(45, 5): 'payload' is declared here.
```

Forget the fact that the error is very difficult to understand. Eventually I managed to understand that `createStandardAction('FETCH')<Payload>()` returns `PayloadAC<"FETCH", Payload>` or `EmptyAC<"FETCH">` according to the checks `[Payload] extends [undefined] ? unknown extends Payload ...`.
The thing is that I don't really care wether Payload is undefined or not. I am fine with setting payload as undefined: `{type: 'FETCH', payload: undefined }`. But I don't know how to declare that in typescript.
This forces me to define the return value of the function as `PayloadAC<string, Payload> | EmptyAC<string>` which causes me other problems, for example:

```
const action = getAction<MyType>();
const { payload } = action; // <--- Here I get an exception that payload may not exists
```

In this example I don't really mind to get payload as undefined but typescript is yelling at me.

How do I fix this mess?

Comment: Have you tried something along the lines of `function getAction<Payload>():PayloadAC<string, Payload>  | undefined`?

Comment: getAction() can't return undefined. It can return PayloadAC or EmptyAC

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't care if payload is undefined it sounds like the return type is indeed `PayloadAC<string, Payload> | EmptyAC<string>`.  Yes, you will get errors if you then try and access the payload.  This makes it sound like you actually DO care if payload is undefined.

Also, there is no reason `const { payload } = action;` should give you an error if payload is undefined.  [Example here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwApwJ4A2A9nACbIDeAsAFDL3KJjBEgBcyAzmFKAOYBuWg2QAHfMTIcQAVwC2AI2hCaAX1q1QkWIhQBROaLB5KwhkxbsuPfivU1aMGSATNWyPhDAAVTPwAUoKIyYBwKREQEEHAgAJSmdAzAMMiBIMFg8dSJIvRQXjJQIJSMrpYcAOTeegDK3hUANGISJKQcAMzIqioiqsgQBJwo2bkM+WCFxRSlblZVtfVdPQz29rQIrNzIWPzIALweXr4B8IMQsSobIFvT4oStXfvbfiCC65uREAB0xHz+AAZ3SSkPYAEgoQNaqn+FyAA).  So maybe you are doing something else with payload where a value is expected?

Comment: You can look on this example and see the error I get :
http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwApwJ4A2A9nACbIDeAsAFDL3KJjBEgBcyAzmFKAOYBuWg2QAHfMTIcQAVwC2AI2hCaAX1q1QkWIhQBROaLB5KwhkxbsuPfivU0NNGDJAJmrZAigQ4kALJEpBAEADJEfMAIABRm9BasHOhYuIQk5AA+yAZGeAA0tACUpnQMsZ6s3JRiEmnIqsgAvIxulipl3mAyUCDVqWRtarRAA

Comment: Ok.  Would something like this work: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOrDACwApwJ4A2A9nACbIDeAsAFDL3KJjBEgBcyAzmFKAOYBuWg2QAHfMTIcQAVwC2AI2hCaAX1q1QkWIhQBROaLB5KwhkxbsuPfivU1aMGSATNWyTHE65CJUgApRIk5OYAUCCB9JUg50LCi-ZAAfZAMjPABKDiCQsIiEsmRgTjQMHAlE6joGKAgwGSgQZABycV8yZqKmnNDwyIqyOw0aJxc3JoRauEgAWSJSCAIAGSI+YAR-M3oLVliygvIUtOMAGloM02r6LaKYZH9PbwGAnZAMi6qREQRWbkoxZ7IVTIAC8jFclhUXxqdQa3WeUIYwMWnBQn2hyFq9UayFkBAIiPo9lo9iAA